# Using if statements in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

Is it possible to set up if statements in the `response` event and the render item implementation? I have two json files and use data attributes in `#searchbox` and `.searchbar` to get the urls. Since the files objects are different, I think I need to use two different responses and markups. Can I set up a switch statment or if statements like the following? I'm getting some kind of undefined error with the code.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.js:9597
```

I can see the json file is being returned, but the autocomplete doesn't show up. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<input type='text' data-search="jsonfileA" id="searchbox">
<input type='text' data-search="jsonfileB" class="searchbar">
```

Code:

```
$( "#searchbox,.searchbar" ).each(function(){
    var search = $(this).data('search');
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: search,
                dataType:"json",
                data:{q:request.term},
                success: function( data ) {
                 response($.map(data.products, function( item)
                   { 
                    if ($(this).is('#searchbox')) {
                       return {
                        label:item.name,
                        category:item.category
                        }
                   }else {
                       return { 
                       title:item.title,
                       description:item.description
                       }
                    }  
                   });
                 )};
            });
        }
    })
    .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        var inner_html;
        if ($(this).is('#searchbox')) {  
            inner_html = ''+item.label+'<p>'+item.category+'';
        }
        else {
            inner_html = ''+item.title+'<p>'+item.description+'';
        }
        return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append(inner_html)  
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Comment: Please include the exact text of the error with your question.

Comment: @Pointy The error that I got is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.js:9597`

Comment: Have you used the browser developer tools to check what exactly is being returned from your ajax call?

Comment: @Pointy The file is successfully returned, but the autocomplete doesn't show up. I can see the json file from Network tab in Chrome

Comment: Well I don't know if this is the only problem but for `$(this)` to work in your "success" callback, add `context: this` to the ajax options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `var $this = $(this)` inside the `.each` function and then use `$this` to refer to the autocomplete `input` in the `.each` and `.ajax` functions.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/z9LHB/)

```
$( "#searchbox,.searchbar" ).each(function(){

    var $this = $(this), // declared here
        search = $this.data('search'); // used here

    $this.autocomplete({ // used here
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: search,
                dataType:"json",
                data:{q:request.term},
                success: function( data ) {
                 response($.map(data.products, function( item)
                   { 
                    if ($this.is('#searchbox')) { // used here
                       return {
                        label:item.name,
                        category:item.category
                    }
                   } else { 
                   // rest of your code - replace any remaining references to the autocomplete input with $this
```